# JavaScript Array Looping

Tags: javascript

So I've got this piece of code below:

```
var divs = ["A", "B", "C"];
for (var i = 0, div; div = divs[i]; i++) {  
  print(div);
}
```

As I understand it, the for loop iterates through every element of the divs array and prints them.  I however fail to understand how the loop terminates.  Could somebody explain that to me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The loop terminates because `div = divs[i]` will be `undefined` when `i` is out of bounds.

Since `undefined` is a falsey value, the condition is considered to have not been met, and the loop stops.

Note that you're doing an *assignment*, and not a comparison. The assignment expression returns the value that was assigned, and that value is used for the condition.

You should also note that this technique is reliable only if none of the members of the Array are falsey. If there was a `0` in the Array for example, it would terminate early.

Answer (score 2):

The part of the `for` loop that defines whether or not to terminate is the second part:

```
div = divs[i]
```

Normally, you would use `i < divs.length` which yields `true` or `false`. Here, the expression evaluates to `"A"`, `"B"`, `"C"`, and `undefined`, subsequently. `undefined` acts like `false` here: it terminates the loop. That's because `undefined` is a "falsy" value like `false` is. (The letter strings are not.)